# Namespace issue C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

C# and WPF n00b here. I'm trying to set a custom style for a cell in a GridView, based on the value of the cell. So I'm defining a class in my namespace which returns the style and in my xaml I'm defining what each style looks like. The problem is I get an error saying

> The name "StatusStyle" does not exist in the namespace
>   "WpfApplication6"

I'm sure I'm doing something super n00bie, can you please help me figure it out.

**C# Code**

```
namespace WpfApplication6
{
public class StatusStyle : StyleSelector
    {
        public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
        // returns the style..
        }
    }
// ...
}
```

**WPF**

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" x:Class="WpfApplication6.Window1"
        xmlns:my="WpfApplication6"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="500" Width="500">
        <Grid>


            <Grid.Resources>
                <my:StatusStyle x:Key="statusStyle">
                    <my:StatusStyle.greenStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        </Style>
                    </my:StatusStyle.greenStyle>
                    <my:StatusStyle.redStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </Style>
                    </my:StatusStyle.redStyle>
                </my:StatusStyle>
            </Grid.Resources>
    ...
    <Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've to qualify with `clr-namespace`.

This code will work for you.

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" x:Class="WpfApplication6.Window1"            
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="500" Width="500">
        <Grid>   

            <Grid.Resources>
                <my:StatusStyle x:Key="statusStyle">
                    <my:StatusStyle.greenStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        </Style>
                    </my:StatusStyle.greenStyle>
                    <my:StatusStyle.redStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </Style>
                    </my:StatusStyle.redStyle>
                </my:StatusStyle>
            </Grid.Resources>
    ...
    <Grid>
</Window>
```